# Assigning value to passed references using variable argument list (error in VS2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, variadic-functions

The following code compiles and runs in Code::Blocks, but issues and error in VS2010:
"Undhandled exception at 0x770815de in test2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing to location 0x00000002."

I realise the code is sort of dangerous, it's basically prototyping an idea I have for another project. What I want to be able to do is pass a reference to any given number of ints followed by a value. Then put this value into the referenced ints and bob's your uncle. And it works, which is nice. But not in VS2010 which bothers me. I'm not the most experience with pointers, so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it's just this kind of operation is not something that VS2010 is fond of. Which is a problem because the project I'm testing this for is all in VS2010! So I need this to work for that!

EDIT: I'm sorry, I'm new to the Code:Blocks thing. I guess I should specify which compiler I use in Code::Blocks? :D I use the miniGW (or something) implementation of the GNU GCC Compiler (or something like that). I hope it makes sense to you experience Code::Blocks users!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

using namespace std;

void getMonkey(int Count, ... )
{
   int test;
   va_list Monkeys;
   va_start(Monkeys, Count );

   for(int i = 0; i < (Count / 2); i++ )
   {
      *va_arg(Monkeys, int*) = va_arg(Monkeys, int);
   }

   va_end(Monkeys);
}

int main()
{
   int monkey1 = 0;
   int monkey2 = 0;
   int monkey3 = 0;

   getMonkey(6, &monkey1, 2, &monkey2, 4, &monkey3, 5);

   cout << monkey1 << " " << monkey2 << " " << monkey3;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The two `va_arg` calls are not sequenced with respect to one another, so your code does in fact have undefined behaviour.

Comment: They aren't? I thought they were, because I do call one then the other :/ I just learned about stdarg a few minutes ago and I thought this was how I'm supposed to use it? I make a total of Count number of va_arg calls. Tbh I'm not entirerly sure what the last parameter of va_start means either, so I just assume Count means the the total number of parameter is the arg list.

Comment: I think what kerrek is saying is that it is up to the compiler to chose the order of the assignation. You could save the pointer and then give him the value.

Comment: In the expression `a = b`, it is unspecified which of the subexpressions `a` and `b` gets evaluated first. That's just a language (non-)rule.

Comment: I did not know that. Derp! I just assumed it was implicit in the standard that lvalue gets evaluated first. Ty. EDIT: THAT WORKS! TIL something about the c++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out lvalues and rvalues are NOT evaluated in the order I assumed! TY stackoverflow!

Updated getMonkey method:

```
void getMonkey(int Count, ... )
{
   int test;
   va_list Monkeys;
   va_start(Monkeys, Count );

   for(int i = 0; i < (Count / 2); i++ )
   {
      int* tempMonkeyPtr = va_arg(Monkeys, int*); //herp
      *tempMonkeyPtr = va_arg(Monkeys, int);      //derp
   }

   va_end(Monkeys);
}
```

Yey! I'm getting a hang of this pointer business me thinks!